# Scroll Sections with Custom Scrollbar (Nice Scroll) -- Animation jerks on fast Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, nicescroll

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Imran_Bughio/4Hm6g/1/)**

I am using **[Scroll Section](https://github.com/guins/jQuery.scrollSections)** with **[Nice Scroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)**.

Every thing is fine but if i scroll really quickly it start producing these animation jerks.

**HTML:**

```
    <section id="top" class="root_section">
        This is a section 1
    </section>

    <section id="mid" class="root_section">
        This is a section 2
        <section id="mid-test-1" class="mid-inner-test-1 root_section"> Mid section </section>
    </section>

    <section id="bot" class="root_section">
        This is a section 3
    </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body{
    height:!00%;
}
.root_section{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.mid-inner-test-1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('section.root_section').scrollSections({
    mousewheel: true,
});

$("body").niceScroll({
    easing: 'easeOutCircle'
});
```

**What i have tried:**

If i declear `mousewheel: false` on `scrollSection()` function it starts working fine but it no longer switches the section on single scroll down or scroll up.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS to:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/4Hm6g/2/)

```
$('body').scrollSections({
    mousewheel: true,
});

$("body").niceScroll({
    easing: 'easeOutCircle'
});
```

You are giving the plugin conflicting information, by instructing two different elements. You are effectively applying it to your `body` but then detecting the scroll event for mouse wheel on a child seperately.

Comment: It seems it only sticks on body tag for example try to stop scroll bar b/w section 2 and 3 it wont go any where... what it should have done is scroll to 2nd or 3 -- the one nearest

Comment: @ImranBughio - it isnt completely clear what behaviour you're expecting

Comment: check this **[DEMO](http://lab.stephaneguigne.com/js/jquery-scrollsections/example/callbacks.html)** -- i have achieved this state but custom scroll bar is causing animation problems.